# How can you price attribute options in drupal commerce properly?

Tags: 7, commerce

Currently I am creating a site for a repair shop. Say I am repairing a laptop motherboard:

Motherboard Repair = $100

As with a motherboard repair, it could consist of a power slot repair, cpu replacement, memory replacement, or video card replacement. I charge $100 for any of those repairs, but I consider them as a Motherboard repair. I want to create a page where they can select one of those, but not create a SKU for it. How can this be done?

In Ubercart, it would just be 1 product and 1 attribute with those 4 options. Since they aren't tangible products they don't need an SKU. Its more of a reference for the business owner to know what to repair which is selected by the customer on checkout.

Now say if I did have varying prices for each of those options. How can that be done too?

Comment: Do your other products need a SKU? If not then you could just hide the SKU field from displaying and put anything you want in the SKU field when creating the new page.

Comment: I just want to confirm. Commerce is taking away the attribute field because in reality every type of option is technically a product in itself? I'm still trying to wrap my head around this as I see it as just 1 product item, but to adjust to the Commerce way of thinking I have to think of each attribute option as its own product. Let me know if that makes sense or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The core way to do this is through fields on the product line item type used to generate the Add to Cart form. This is facilitated through the Commerce Customizable Products module, which allows you to create any number of product line item types so you can use different line item fields for different products / product types. Fields added to the line item type can be included in the Add to Cart form, and then their values can be inspected by your product pricing rules to alter the price of the line item accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

As per your requirement you want to give option to the user to select one from many option from your given list while purchasing the product, but you don't want to create separate SKU for each of them. I think [Commerce Option](http://drupal.org/project/commerce_option) module will work for you in this case...I hope it help...Good Luck :)

Comment: Commerce Option hasn't been updated sine 2011 and there are currently 36 open issues with it. i fear if i were to use it today, it would cause issues in the long run. I wonder how did Ryan the main maintainer of the project would deal with this question.

Comment: Then better think of improving this same module, it would be helpful for you in long run...